# Connect points with a line

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data looks like this

```
score<-c(3.2,3.5,5.4,5.5)
subject<-c('math','math','reading','reading')
sex<-c('men','women')

data<-data.frame(sex,score,subject)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=score,y=subject,color=sex)) +
  geom_point()
```

I would like to connect the dots (between the subjects from men to women) to show gender gap. This doesn't seem to be possible by just adding geom_line().

Comment: `aes(x=score,y=subject,color=sex, group=sex)`

Comment: I guess the group should rather be “subject”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code (from yours above) generates the same plot, but now the points are linked between *sex* for each *subject*.

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=score,y=subject)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(color=sex))
```

[image: plot]

Notice that *color=sex* must be defined just for *geom_point()* instead of for the general ggplot fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `group` like mentioned in the comments:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=score,y=subject,color=sex, group = subject)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(col = "black")
```

Output:

[image]